# Multiple facebook user id for the same user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've a problem with facebook login.
I've created an app in a facebook developer's account. Next I've used the facebook PHP SDK to make user login and:

- In the PHP SDK response, return this fb id: 884035841685689
- At the following address: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer if I search with this query "me?fields=id" return this fb id: 750153425073932
- At the following address: http://findmyfbid.com/ if I paste the user's facebook link in the textbox it will return this fb id: 100002378440884

I don't understand why with the same user account, return three different facebook id.

Comment: [Please show your code](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i-w600/keep-calm-and-show-the-code.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User IDs are "App Scoped" nowadays.

- The first one is the App Scoped ID of your own App.
- The second one is the App Scoped ID of the "Graph API Explorer App". Select your own App and you will get the same ID as with the PHP SDK.
- The last one is actually the "real" ID. You only get that one by scraping the user profile, which is not allowed on Facebook.

More information about App Scoped IDs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I've understand ;)

Comment: glad i could help. don´t forget to accept my answer :)